# What is the largest object on which the Yarkovsky effect has been observed?

Tags: orbit, observational-astronomy, rotation, asteroids

The [Yarkovsky effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarkovsky_effect) is responsible for changes in the rotation and orbit of some celestial bodies, most notably asteroids. It has been measured on asteroids, such as [6489 Golevka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6489_Golevka) and [1999 RQ36](http://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/the-yarkovsky-effect-pushing-asteroids-around-with-sunlight).

What is the largest object on which the Yarkovsky effect has been observed? [Scholarpedia has an excellent article and list of asteroids](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Yarkovsky_and_YORP_effects#Detection_of_Yarkovsky_effect), but the list isn't necessarily complete, and I don't know if the effect has been detected on other (non-asteroid) bodies.

Comment: only slightly related: [Would the Yarkovsky effect ever be faster than a solar sail from a 1 AU orbit to the Sun?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44624/12102)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Vokrouhlicky et al. 2015](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01249) Yarkovsky forces can be measured for small bodies with diameters up to 30-40 km. The largest object they have in their list of Yarkovsky detections is 4179 Toutatis with a diameter of (only) 2.8 km. I am not aware if Yarkovsky forces have been measured on anything larger than asteroids.